# Rabin-Karp: rolling hash computation adds a large prime number to previously computed hash

Tags: string, montecarlo, rolling-computation, rabin-karp

I think I conceptually understand RabinKarp pattern matching algorithm using rolling hash. While going through a sample implementation [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html), I find that a large prime number `q` is added to the previously computed rolling hash.

```
for (int i = m; i < n; i++) {
            // Remove leading digit, add trailing digit, check for match. 
            txtHash = (txtHash + q - RM*txt.charAt(i-m) % q) % q; //Why +q here?
            txtHash = (txtHash*R + txt.charAt(i)) % q; 

            // match
            int offset = i - m + 1;
            if ((patHash == txtHash) && check(txt, offset))
                return offset;
        }
```

I am not sure why this is needed. Can I get some help with this?

In my limited testing, I get the same result whether or not `q` term in included.

Does this have something to do with which version of algorithm (Monte Carlo/Las Vegas) is being implemented?

Comment: `+ q` looks like a mistake to me as well, for what it's worth.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you! Can you please also shed some light on why we get correct result when `+q` is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+q` term is there to avoid dealing with negative numbers.

We want `txtHash`to always lie in the interval `[0;q[`, without this `+q` it could also be in `]-q;0[`.

This could lead to missing the pattern. e.g if `patHash = 0xdead` but you compute `txtHash = -q+0xdead`. Those two values are equal mathematically `mod q` but different with Java taken `% q`.

Comment: if I run the algorithm without +q, would it still work. the reason I am asking is I just learned that -3%7 = 4%7 = 4, so having a negative intermediate hash will not have any side effect as long as there is module by q.

Comment: `%` in Java is not the modulo operator, but the remainder https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3 . Thus in Java, `-3%7=-3`; `4%7=4` and of course `-3 != 4`. See e.g. https://programming.guide/java/remainder-modulo-operator-negative-numbers.html

Comment: Thanks for lightening up that for me. I guess I understand the overall idea now, but I am still having a bit of difficulty in understanding the exact math.